# Accessing python application hosted on Azure VM (Windows OS) from outside

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have hosted a python flask web application on azure virtual machine (Windows OS). When I start the python application, it gets hosted on 127.0.01:5000 i.e. localhost. I can access this in browser by providing localhost:5000 in URL. I want to access this from outside the VM machine. The problem here is Azure VMs have an internal IP and external IP.

I tried to use the external VM IP as parameter in app.run() but it throwing error and not able to host it on external IP.

```
app.run(HOST = “external Azure VM  IP”)
```

It is throwing below error when trying to host on external IP.

"Error : s.bind(get_sockaddr(hostname, port, address_family))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context"

Is there any way I can make it work?

Also, I tried hosting it on azure web app services  and I was successfully able to host there but I am not able to install external libraries like (beautifulsoup4) into flask application hosted on Azure App Services.

Answer (score 1):

you need to listen on internal IP (probably better if you listen on *), not on external IP. vm is not aware of the external ip. it will get request on its internal ip, not external.

You also need to open port(s) on firewall and on [Network Security Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).

ps. package management on [Azure App Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/29/install-native-python-modules-on-azure-web-apps-api-apps/)